# AJAX synchronous request and operations while waiting

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

I Have ExtJS client-side programm that communicates with server using synchronous AJAX. Over 95% responses incoming at less of 1 second but there a few cases when server can execute commands during 10 seconds or more. That's why I need some mechanism that can tell to user that this is not a bug ("pls wait" form)

So. I need something like

1. send request;
2. setTimeOut('show loading form', 2 sec);
3. wait for response
4. close loading form
5. process response.

Is there some way to execute some function while waiting synchronous AJAX response?

P. S. I use synchronous because of legacy, there is no way to correct it (best way - over 6 month of work).

Comment: No, you can't justify synchronous ajax ever. IE9 crashes and burns when you use sjax. Refactor the bad code.

Comment: I need it for Chrome And Firefox (last version only)

Comment: In startup we response all request at less of 1 second by hand.

Comment: Is not possible for my system. It on Delphi, processing over 9 Tb of data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such methods, but it can be implement by hooking all events while async request is going...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It's called *asynchronous* jax. This means whilst your doing your HTTP request you can do other things.

However, with *synchronous* jax, you can't do that.

JavaScript is single threaded.

This means a synchronous ajax request will block your one and only thread.

The best you can do is show a loading screen before *every single* sjax request and remove it after every request.

Comment: i can implement script language with 1 thread wich can do that, via c++.

Comment: @TheHorse sorry what? You can. You can implement a script language with _one thread_ which can do _two things_ in parallel? Do it.

Comment: Not parallel. Did you know about multiplexer?